# The object already exists

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App** (WINRT). **Sometimes** my mainpage crashes and debugger doesnot even handle it. I tried applying try-catch to every line but it was not helping.

It happens sometimes and not always.

While debugging it directly goes into App.g.i.cs:

```
    #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
        }
```

> **e:** {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>       {System.Exception: The object already exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071392)}
>         Message = "The object already exists.\r\n"

Is it XAML problem? I checked every line of XAML, I didnt find any problem.  How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to check where does the issue show up? App constructor, launched event, page constructor, resuming, navigated events? It's hard to help with so little infromation and without any code.

Comment: sender is : {Merakyahoga.com.Merakyahoga_com_WindowsPhone_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider}

Comment: and i had a breakpoint on every method on App.cs but of no use

Comment: This mostly happens if you move controls or Items between "holders" / List<?> , i.E. "remove Panel from X and add it again to Y" , we really need more code, and yes that codeline catches all "UnhandledExceptions" thats why it jumps there while debugging `global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()`

Comment: Another thing you can try is to check if there is place inside a `non-awaited` `async` method where you Add() items to a ListDictionary. Sometimes the not `await`ing a method swallows the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I read my code line by line and got the bug, I was trying to change the Pivot.SelectedIndex even before Pivot was enabled.

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Hi Atif, 
I have the exact same bug.
Can you explain what "before pivot was enabled" means ?
is this eg : "if (pivot.IsEnabled) pivot.SelectedIndex = 0;" ?
In my case my pivot in not disabled so I don't think it's the root cause